# How to change the color of the x (or y) axis label [manim]

Tags: manim

I'm new on stack**overflow** and I didn't found a solution to the following problem:
I want to change the color of the x (or y) axis label in black.

This is my code (and it doesn't work):

```py
from manimlib.imports import *
from manimlib.Bibli_preda import *
import numpy as np

class Graphx(GraphScene):
    position_graph_o = np.array([-5,-3,0])
    CONFIG = {
        "camera_config":{"background_color":"#ffffff"},
        "x_min": 0,
        "x_max": 400,
        "y_min": 0,
        "y_max": 400,
        "graph_origin": position_graph_o,
        "x_tick_frequency" : 100,
        "y_tick_frequency" : 100,
        "x_labeled_nums" : range(0,500,100),
        "x_axis_label" : "$Temps$",
        "y_axis_height": 5,
        "x_axis_width" : 10,
        "y_axis_label" : "N",
        "x_axis_label_color": "#000000",
        "y_label_color": "#000000",
        "axes_color": "#000000",
        }
```

I get that: https://ibb.co/vq8FrcW

Answer (score 1):

Change this in `x_label` and `y_label` in [this](https://github.com/3b1b/manim/blob/f934bdc61e6709cbb7b56045d6194a83d5a985c3/manimlib/scene/graph_scene.py#L99) line:

```py
x_label = TextMobject(self.x_axis_label,color=BLACK)
```